# How to start with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec, bdd

I have been into rails for the last 3 months. Now I wish to start BDD or TDD.  I want to start with RSpec.  How do I start with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following websites may be of interest:

- http://peepcode.com/products/rspec-basics
- http://www.elctech.com/tutorials/rspec-tutorial
- http://jimmyzimmerman.com/blog/2007/11/simple-tutorials-for-learning-bdd-and-rspec.html

Answer (score 5):

PragProg has a beta book (with the full book shipping in June) by the Authors of RSpec themselves. I am working through it now and it has been fantastic so far! I started going through the peepcode screencasts a few weeks ago, and Sarah Mei is right, they are great. However the book goes a little more in depth where I needed it too (as a complete newbie to BDD myself).

[The RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book)

Answer (score 5):

If you're getting started you might want to try starting with a combination of cucumber and rspec.

Cucumber, is rpecs' higher level integration testing replacement for story runner and is geared towards client readability.

The new RSpec book covers how to do the outside-in development technique and cucumber scenarios feel a lot more tangible to testing beginners IMHO.

Ryan Bates has just this moment posted a [getting started with cucumber](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) screencast (I can't vouch for the content as his file hosting seems borked at the moment but all of his other videos have been very clear).

There was also a recent cucumber BDD talk at Mountain West Ruby Conf that is on confreaks [here](http://mwrc2009.confreaks.com/14-mar-2009-15-00-bdd-with-cucumber-ben-mabey.html).

I have a whack of other cucumber links [here](http://delicious.com/srboisvert/cucumber).